# SQL Server Calculate Ranking

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures, do-while

I have a table with results of a sports event.
The table is in SQL Server 2012. I am looking for a way to fill a ranking column.

The table is like:

Player1  - Level1 -  30 Points

Player2  - Level1 -  25 Points

Player3  - Level2 -  33 Points

I would like to add a column with the ranking and calculate that based on the points and the level of the player. (Ranking starts at 1 for each level)
In my example Player 1 will be in first place, player 2 in second and player 3 in first.

How can I build a function or procedure that loops over the table and fills the ranking column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DENSE_RANK()` window function:

```
SELECT Player, Level, Points,
       DENSE_RANK()  OVER ( ORDER BY CASE WHEN Level = 'Level1' THEN 1
                                          WHEN Level = 'Level2' THEN 2
                                     END,
                                     Points DESC) AS rnk
FROM Players
```

The above will assign `rnk` = 1 to Player1, `rnk` = 2 to Player2 and `rnk` = 3 to Player3.

If, in case of a tie, e.g. Player2 having 30 points, you want `rnk` for Player3 to be 3, then you should use `RANK` instead of `DENSE_RANK`.

If, on the other hand, you want to partition ranking by `Level` then use `PATITION BY` clause:

```
SELECT Player, Level, Points,
       DENSE_RANK()  OVER ( PARTITION BY Level 
                            ORDER BY Points DESC) AS rnk
FROM Players
```

The above will assign `rnk` = 1 to Player1, `rnk` = 2 to Player2 and `rnk` = 1 to Player3.

Comment: This works fine in a view but what if 2 players have the same points, does it give the possibility to skip a place? It's common that when two players are in first place, that second place is skipped.

Comment: If you want both of these players to have 1 as rnk and 3rd player to have 3 as rnk, then simply use `RANK` instead of `DENSE_RANK`.

Comment: Nice, can i write it to the table as well for later use in reports?

Comment: @Jan I think the best option would be to create a view containing the ranking window function, then use this view in your reports.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [rank()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) or [dense_rank()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) functions:

```
SELECT *
      ,RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [level] ORDER BY Points DESC)
FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
DECLARE @Levels TABLE
    (
      Level NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      Ranking INT
    )
DECLARE @Players TABLE
    (
      Player NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      Level NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      Point INT
    )

INSERT  INTO @Levels
VALUES  ( 'Level1', 1 ),
        ( 'Level2', 2 )

INSERT  INTO @Players
VALUES  ( 'Player1', 'Level1', 30 ),
        ( 'Player2', 'Level1', 25 ),
        ( 'Player3', 'Level2', 33 )


SELECT  p.Player, p.Level, p.Point ,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER ( ORDER BY l.Ranking, p.Point DESC ) AS Rank
FROM    @Players p
        JOIN @Levels l ON l.Level = p.Level
ORDER BY Rank
```

Output:

```
Player  Level   Point   Rank
Player1 Level1  30      1
Player2 Level1  25      2
Player3 Level2  33      3
```